# Reconstruct cartesian image from back-projection Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, tomography-reconstruction

I'm doing an exercise to reconstruct an CT-scan image from its sinogram (given).

From the sinogram, implementing the central slice theorem, I did the 1D FFT (after zero padding)

```
sino_fft = fftshift(fft(fftshift(sinogram)));
```

and recover the back-projection through the 2D inverse FFT

```
backprojection = fftshift(ifft2(fftshift(sino_fft)));
```

Now I should convert the polar back projection to cartesian coordinate and reconstruct the grayscale image. I'm not sure how do it. `backprojection` is a double complex, so I converted into  x-y with

```
theta = 0:180/(size(backprojection,1)-1):180;
[x,y] = pol2cart(theta,abs(backprojection));
```

and at this point I have a scattered data set. The hint from the exercise is to sum iteratively from all the angles to get the recovered image. But I don't understand. Just do `image = x+y`? In this case I get an empty gray image.

[image]

Edit after @Christoph Rackwitz comment:

If I remove the inner `fftshift` from sino_fft and backprojection I get a splitted fourier transform.

[image]

while with my code I get a centered fourier transform.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be some sort of tomography from your words, but you have not specify which one. That would help. Also it would help describe which algorithm are you trying to implement in particular. i.e. a backprojection of CT (which your words kinda fit) is not a 2D IFFT.

Comment: Yes sorry. It's a CT scan tomography. I added few lines. I've a sort of guide for the exercise saying: compute 1D FFT of the sinogram, filter the result to improve the quality (I skipped it in my question), compute the 2D IFFT to get the back projection and convert it from polar to cartesian to get the final image

Comment: I think the innermost fftshift is wrong. does not require application at all, and only makes sense in the frequency domain, not the space domain. the code is incomplete. `sino_filtered` is undefined.

Comment: Removed `sino_filtered`. Is useless to the question, sorry. I copied-pasted from matlab. If i remove the inner ffshift I get a splitted image. I add a plot with your tip.

Comment: well that's progress. remember, fftshift may only be applied to spectra, not spatial domain, and it merely rolls _the spectrum_ so DC is in the center. this merely makes application of masks/filters easier, DC being in the center instead of the corners.

Comment: I also saw this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61260808/implementing-a-filtered-backprojection-algorithm-using-the-central-slice-theorem) doing something very similar. I skipped the filtering part in my question because it is not neccessary, but clearly it is needed before doing the ifft. I need to understand how from polar go to cartesian to check the result (because plotting the back-projected image is not helping)